# Blender 2.8 UI is different on Windows 8

Tags: interface

I have a Windows 8 PC and I'm using Blender 2.8. However, some of the UI elements are different when compared to a Windows 10 PC on which I used Blender. The Windows 10 PC's UI was completely normal, but for me, it's a little weird.
[image]

As you can see, the buttons are only half-filled by the blue colour and moreover, it's not flat. The drop-down menus too have a gradient which becomes more transparent towards the end, making it slightly irritating and difficult to see. I tried resetting the theme, but it looks like this is the default theme. Is there any way I could change the UI?

[image]

This is how I want it to be. As you can see, the buttons are filled and flat and the UI is cleaner.

Comment: Are they exactly the same build?

Comment: Yes. I had this problem a little while ago too, but couldn't find a solution. Now it's really annoying because I have to keep peering at the monitor, trying to found out what option I am clicking.

Comment: It can't be the same build. The one has the tab menu in the properties editor still horizontal, and with colored icons. This is an older build for sure. And this also explains the theming differences. You can change quite a few things in the theming. But the colored icons are gone. They are monochrome now.